# Handle click count for documents in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am having a page with documents loaded in SharePoint 2010. I have three buttons below each documents in the page and they are 'Like','Unlike' and 'Comment'. So whenever people go there and see the documents they can click on any buttons of their wish.

My question is how to take the hit count of these buttons seperately and display it for each document. Is it possible to create a list with having these three columns and handle it using Client-Side scripting. Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

Comment: here are some thoughts:
in the document library, create three columns with Like/Unlike/Comment.
And on the page embed some javascript, using CSOM or ajax webservice calls to update the counter on click event.

Answer (score 0):

Each item in SharePoint has a property bag that can contain ad-hoc data like this. You could certainly add additional columns to store this data and update those columns but that does mean that users could easily manipulate the values via the UI. Since the property bag is only accessible via the various API's, you wouldn't have this issue.

For an example of accessing the property bag via CSOM (which would be your best option since I'm assuming you want your users to be able to like, unlike and comment without refreshing the page each time), see this post [reading and writing property bag values using CSOM](http://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2013/05/22/building-sharepoint-hosted-apps-reading-and-writing-to-property-bags/)

Another thing to consider for comments is the existing notes functionality that exists in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013. These comments are ties into the social functionality and may give you a bit more bang for your buck. To show the comments page for a particular list item see this post [SharePoint Social Data using Javascript](http://www.techbubbles.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-social-data-using-java-script/)